# How to configure slickedit to work with clearcase?

Tags: slickedit

I am using slickedit on my windows machine. Currently I use ssh and copy files back and forth to edit files on slickedit and move them back to compile on UNIX. 
My new code base resides on UNIX with clearcase source control. How can I configure slickedit to use with clearcase code base ?

Comment: You'd be much better off using a Unix version of Slickedit. Copying files back and forth is going to end up causing problems one day.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Yes agree, copying back and forth has been quite painful. Let me see how their unix version is? Thanks Greg.
I'm assuming their unix version is easy to configure with clearcase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Greg that the easiest path may be to get a Unix version ... but if the cost of buying a new version may be prohibitive. Her are three more options:

(1) You already said that SSH is available to you, if you have SSH you have SFTP, so you could edit the files through slickedit's FTP Tool ([See screenshot of VSE's FTP/SFTP file-selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5BMS.png))  This typically okay for one or two remote files, typically cfor config files on remote servers - I never used it for a complete software project.

Options #2 & #3 assume that you can have a Windows clearcase client.

(2) As much as I despise ClearCase's dynamic views (did they ever get that to work on Win7?  Its been a while since I used it), you could give that a shot.  You could share the same dynamic view with your windows machine, edit on windows and build on linux.  Even remote debugging SHOULD work if you get/compile a cross-gdb (built on cygwin for your linux target)

(3) I currently develop on a Mac for a Linux target.  I have a VM on the MAC using VirtualBox which has a pretty smooth 'Shared Folders' feature.   If you get a CC client on your windows machine you can share your snapshot view directory to the VM, edit under windows and build/test in the VM.

Let me know if you want me to elaborate on any of these

good luck

p.s. I forgot to mention that IMO out of the Windows, Linux and Mac versions of VSE, Widnows seems the most solid (mac being the least).  So an instinct to stick with what you have and know is not a bad one ...

Comment: nhed, Thanks for your suggestions, very helpful. I am gonna try and work with option 1 for now. Although, I am trying to figure out how to access the file inside the clearcase codebase using FTP option in VSE.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: @Karthik I'm not sure if you can have SFTP based files in a project. So the option has a strong drawback ... (I listed it first to get it out of the way)